# Succinct way to write a mixture of chars and bytes?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I'm trying to write an index file that follows the format of a preexisting (and immutable) text file.

The file is fixed length, with 11 bytes of string (in ASCII) followed by 4 bytes of long for a total of 15 bytes per line.

Perhaps I'm being a bit dim, but is there an simple way to do this? I get the feeling I need to open up two streams to write one line - one for the string and one for the bytes - but that feels wrong.

Any hints?

Comment: Have you tried `System.IO.BinaryWriter`?

Comment: Thanks Marc, you're correct, it's an int.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `BitConverter` to convert between an `int`/`long` and an array of `byte`s. This way you would be able to write eleven bytes followed by four bytes, followed by eleven more bytes, and so on.

```
byte[] intBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(intValue); // returns 4-byte array
```

Converting to bytes: [`BitConverter.GetBytes(int)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/44xk6h48).

Converting back to `int`: [`BitConverter.ToInt32(byte\[\], int)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.toint32)

If you are developing a cross-platform solution, keep in mind the following note from the documentation (thanks to [`uriDium`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/62544/uridium) for the comment):

> The order of bytes in the array returned by the GetBytes method depends on whether the computer architecture is little-endian or big-endian.

Comment: Keep in mind the Endianess if this needs to be cross platform.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is largely as I'd suspected. To clarify with relation to my problem - what should I be using to write the file? BinaryWriter as suggested in a comment?

The string needs to be written in ASCII encoding so I end up, when opening it in notepad, with a pattern of comprehensible text followed by bytes, which is where I'm getting confused.

Comment: @JoshuaMee Yes, you use `BinaryWriter`. Since you are writing an `int` as a binary, not as a sequence of ASCII characters representing decimal digits, notepad will show text followed by junk. However, when  you read the data back, you should be able to get a normal string from the first 11 bytes, and the same `int` as you wrote from the remaining four.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, as an additional note if anyone else ends up reading this - writing the string is best done as a char array for this purpose as a string gets prepended with a string length it seems.